# jqgrid Data not populating the Grid

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

This is my first attempt with JQgrid and I am confused from the documentation as to if I need the `jsonmap` attribute with in my `colmodel`. As of now I’m getting all of the data but from firebug I see that all I’m getting in each col is:

`<td aria-describedby="list_MEMBERID" title="" style="" role="gridcell">&nbsp;</td>`

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong exactly?

The Json:

```
{
"ROWS": [
    {
        "ID": 508,
        "CELLS": {
            "PHONE": "847-382-8872",
            "STATE": "IL",
            "ZIP": 60010,
            "NAME": "Norton's U.S.A.",
            "DESC": "We sell only products made in the United States!We offer an eclectic mix of common household items from toys to tools, glassware to garden supplies, fashions to food and so much more.  When you shop at Norton's U.S.A, you help keep America working!  ",
            "CITY": "Riverwoods",
            "ADDR": "400 Lageschulte Street"
        }
    }
],
"PAGE": 1,
"RECORDS": 1,
"TOTAL": 1
}
```

The Javascript:

```
$(function(){ 
  $("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'cfc/buildData.cfc?method=getDining',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:['Member ID','Member Name', 'Address','City','Zip Code','State', 'Phone', 'Description'],
    colModel :[ 
      {name:'MEMBERID', index:'MEMBERID', jsonmap:'MEMBERID', width:60}, 
      {name:'NAME', index:'NAME', jsonmap:'NAME', width:90}, 
      {name:'ADDR', index:'ADDR', jsonmap:'ADDR', width:80, align:'right'},
      {name:'CITY', index:'CITY', jsonmap:'CITY', width:80, align:'right'}, 
      {name:'ZIP', index:'ZIP', jsonmap:'ZIP', width:80, align:'right'},
      {name:'STATE', index:'STATE', jsonmap:'STATE', width:80, align:'right'},
      {name:'PHONE', index:'PHONE', jsonmap:'PHONE', width:80, align:'right'},  
      {name:'DESC', index:'DESC', jsonmap:'DESC', width:200, sortable:false} 
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    sortname: 'MEMBERID',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    caption: 'Lake County Members',

    jsonReader : {
       root: "ROWS",
       page: "PAGE",
       total: "TOTAL",
       records: "RECORDS",
       repeatitems: true,
       cell: "CELLS",
       id: "MEMBERID",
       subgrid: {root:"ROWS", 
          repeatitems: true, 
          cell:"CELLS"
       }
     }

  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data) about `jsonReader` and `jsonmap` is really difficult for the first reading.

The most important property of the `jsonReader` is `repeatitems`. Default value is `repeatitems: true`. It means that the format of the rows of data in the JSON should be

```
{"id" :"1", "cell": ["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]}
```

It's important to mention that the `cell` property should has **array of strings** as the value. **The `jsonmap` property of the `colModel` will be ignored**.

If you would just use `jsonReader: {repeatitems: true}` you would overwrite only one property of the default `jsonReader`. So the format of the data which represent the row in the JSON input should be

```
{"id": "abc", "col1": false, "col3": 123, "col2": "cell12"}
```

In the case **no `cell` property** should be used in the input. The data for the column will be identified **by name** instead of by position in the `cell` array. The property name `col1`, `col2`, `col3` can be either from the `name` property of `colModel` or from the `jsonmap` if it's defined.

In case of more complex format of input like

```
{"id": "abc", "col1": false, "coordinates": {"x": 123, "y": "cell12"}}
```

you can define for the `x` column `jsonmap: coordinates.x` and for the `y` column `jsonmap: coordinates.y`.

In case of your example I would recommend you to change format of the JSON data to

```
{
    "ROWS": [
        {
            "ID": 508,
            "PHONE": "847-382-8872",
            "STATE": "IL",
            "ZIP": 60010,
            "NAME": "Norton's U.S.A.",
            "DESC": "We sell only products made in the United States!We offer an eclectic mix of common household items from toys to tools, glassware to garden supplies, fashions to food and so much more.  When you shop at Norton's U.S.A, you help keep America working!  ",
            "CITY": "Riverwoods",
            "ADDR": "400 Lageschulte Street"
        }
    ],
    "PAGE": 1,
    "RECORDS": 1,
    "TOTAL": 1
}
```

- to remove `'MEMBERID'` from the column model because you don't included any data in the JSON input.
- remove `sortname: 'MEMBERID'` or change it to some existing columns.
- remove all `jsonmap` properties

The `jsonReader` should be used as

```
jsonReader : {
     root: "ROWS",
     page: "PAGE",
     total: "TOTAL",
     records: "RECORDS",
     repeatitems: false,
     id: "ID",
 }
```

The value of ids of the rows of the grid (the ids for `<tr>` elements of the table) will be get from the `'ID'` property of the JSON input. You should be careful with the values for the ids: there must be *unique* on the whole page.

After the above changes the grid will display the data: see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/rajh2504.htm). I added `height: 'auto'` parameter only to reduce the size of unneeded space in the grid.